# n2cms Asp.net give error on Files menu (File Manager)

Tags: n2cms

I am new to n2cms and in our application when ever I click on File manager main menu or try to upload an image it gives error. The error is generic hence so use of showing it here.

My question is there any specific permission or configuration settings needs to be set for adding images in File Manager of n2cms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was with the setting of multiple site host in config file. I changed the multiple site and removed all the child sites. Keeping only applicable site with appropriate startPageID.